# Format: Center 2 lines

Tags: formatting, texniccenter

I would like to center two centered lines between them.
Namely, I would like to center two bullet points and write to their right and to their left. Hope following image helps:

[image: latex formatting issue]

Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Consider giving us a minimal working example (http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), to make it easier for us to help you.  And welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 7):

You could use the `tabular` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{r@{\enspace\textbullet\enspace}l}
Address      & City, State \\
Phone number & Email address
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `\enspace` defines the horizontal spacing on either side of the bullet (thanks to Bernard for this suggestion).

Comment: You might simplify the  syntax, using only two columns with `\begin{tabular}{r@{\enspace\textbullet\enspace}l}`.

Comment: @Bernard - Very nice. I have updated my solution.

Answer (score 4):

this approach defines a one-line command that treats everything but the
bullet as without width.  it ignores accidental spaces in the input.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\cbline}[2]{%
  \centering
  \leavevmode \llap{#1\unskip}%
  \ $\bullet$\ \rlap{\ignorespaces#2}\par
 }
\begin{document}
\cbline{Address}{ City, State}
\cbline{Phone number }{Email address}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Or you can try it the plain TeX way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\doubleline#1#2{%
    \hbox to0.5\linewidth{%
        \hbox to 0.22\linewidth{%
            \hfil%
            #1%
        }\hbox to0.06\linewidth{\hfil\textbullet\hfil}%
        \hbox to0.22\linewidth{%
            #2%
            \hfil%
        }%
    }%
}%
\begin{document}
\doubleline{Address}{City, State}
\doubleline{Phone number}{Email address}
\end{document}
```

The `tabular` method is much clearer, and you could wrap it in a macro pretty easily, too.  This way is chiefly useful as (a) a short study in TeX box-twiddling, which is something I love to do, and (b) potentially more easily customizable, as you can govern total width and the like without having to resort to external packages like `tabularx`. (It's not, since the widths of the boxes hard-coded; but it *could* be.)

This yields:

[image: Boxes to make the "table"]